# SQL unique varchar case sensitivity question

Tags: mysql, sql, case-sensitive, varchar, unique-constraint

I'm trying to populate a SQL table with a list of words. The table itself it pretty simple:

```
CREATE TABLE WORDS(
  ID BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  WORD VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
  PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);
```

The problem I'm running into is this: when I do the following inserts back to back

```
INSERT INTO WORDS(WORD) VALUES('Seth');
INSERT INTO WORDS(WORD) VALUES('seth');
```

The second insert fails with a constraint violation ("Duplicate entry 'seth' for key 'WORD'").

How can I get the `UNIQUE` constraint on `WORD` to be case sensitive?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Looks like mysql is [case insensitive by default](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html):

You probably need to create the column with a case sensitive collation (e.g. utf8_bin):

```
CREATE TABLE WORDS (
    ID BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    WORD VARCHAR(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks. For anyone finding this question later, I had to use the 'utf8_bin' collation because mysql didn't have 'utf8_cs'.

Comment: Thanks @Seth, that was helpful along with Bill's info, utf8_bin applied to my situation as well

Comment: #1273 - Unknown collation: 'utf8_cs'

Comment: Huge disappointment with mysql :-( "Seth" and "seth" are NOT same strings! Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Use **utf8_bin** in case of **utf8_cs**

Comment: I have collation set as `utf8_bin`. And still varchar(50) `FFAB213D-810C-74BD-1B34-E93FC473CF6A` is the same as `ffab213D-810C-74BD-1B34-E93FC473CF6A`  (MariaDB 10)

Comment: For utf8mb4, you can use `SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin` instead.

Comment: Many Thanks man, my clients were about to file case on me.
Use this https://jol.ink

Answer (score 13):

By default MySQL ignores differences in case and trailing spaces on `varchar`.

If you need it to be case sensitive, you can alter the table to be `varchar(...) binary`.

Use `show create table` to better understand how MySQL converts this to full notation.

If you need to pay attention to trailing spaces as well as be case sensitive, use `varbinary` instead of `varchar`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE WORDS CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

Answer (score -4):

I made my UNIQUE key varchar(1000). It worked.

After some trial and error, I found anything greater than or equal to 1100 varchar would fail.

To clarify I did not try between 1001 to 1099.

Hope this helps.