# How can I map mysql varbinary to String in jOOQ code generation

Tags: mysql, varchar, unique-constraint, jooq

MySQL doesn't accept a value like 'foo' if the column is of type varchar with a unique index and has a value 'Foo'.

So I want to change varchar into varbinary,

But [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) maps varbinary to byte[] in Java,

How can I configure jOOQ to resolve this?

Comment: I don't understand why you'd like to change a `varchar` column to `varbinary` in the first place. Could you explain? Is this a case-sensitivity problem (`foo` vs. `Foo`)? In that case, you might want to consider this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448825/sql-unique-varchar-case-sensitivity-question

Comment: Thanks you,but it's not my idea.

Comment: My team is using jooq, It's greate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL `UNIQUE` constraints can be case-insensitive if their underlying column's collation is case-insensitive. So, instead of changing the column data type, you should really fix the collation of the `VARCHAR` column. This is explained here:

[SQL unique varchar case sensitivity question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448825/sql-unique-varchar-case-sensitivity-question)