# is unique attribute in ormlite case sensitive?

Tags: unique, case-sensitive, ormlite

I have a unique constraint on a String field in a table in my database and i was wondering if 
unique attribute in ormlite is case sensitive ?

For example, is "Bob Smith" and " BOB SMITH" the same thing  for the unique constraint ?

Thanks for your answers and your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is database dependent I suspect.  You will need to check your database documentation to see how what it does.  [ORMlite](http://ormlite.com/) doesn't do anything special with the `UNIQUE` SQL clause -- it just uses it.

For example, here's the answer for MySQL: [SQL unique varchar case sensitivity question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448825/sql-unique-varchar-case-sensitivity-question)