# Case-sensitive database search with Active Record

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

**Does Active Record provide a way to generate SQL that forces a text search to be case-sensitive?**

Ruby-on-Rails generators instructed to create a string-type column produce a simple `VARCHAR(255)` field, in a `mysql` database. It turns out that [queries on such columns are case insensitive by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448825/sql-unique-varchar-case-sensitivity-question).

Thus, an Active Record search such as:

```
Secret.where(token: 'abcde')
```

will match records with tokens `abcde`, `ABcdE`, etc.

Without changing the underlying database column (e.g. specifying a `utf8_bin` collation) searches can be made case sensitive by explicitly tweaking the `where` clause:

```
Secret.where('binary token = ?', 'abcde')
```

However, this is database-specific, and I am wondering if Active Record has an idiom to accomplish the same for any database. Just as an example, something resembling the `where.not` construct:

```
Secret.where.binary(token: 'abcde')
```

Wouldn't this be a common enough need?

Comment: `Secret.where('binary token LIKE ? ', '%abcde%')` how about this?

Comment: @Gabbar, this is similar to my own version, in that you are actually writing database-specific SQL. My question is about whether an Active Record abstraction exists.

Comment: I'm not getting you exactly , but so far as i understand Active Record also contact to database in return of sql query to ORM object.

Comment: Active Record searches are NOT case-insensitive by default. Moreover, AR is not about "case sensitivity", it is about SQL constructing and mapping result to the objects. I guess, either you DB settings or `token` column type is the reason why SQL query, generated by `Secret.where(token: 'abcde')`, makes case-insensitive search.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220423/case-insensitive-search-in-rails-model ?

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk, you are right, the question needs editing. But first, at least when the RoR-generated mysql column is a `varchar(255)`, part of an `InnoDB`, `utf8mb4` table, a search like `Secret.where(token: 'abcde')` is indeed case-insensitive. Agree? It is at least conceivable that AR might provide a way to construct (db-specific) SQL that forces the query to be case-sensitive. Am I still missing something?

Comment: @Austio, my question is related, but I think quite distinct from the one you refer to.

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk, please see my extensive edits. Thanks!

Comment: `binary` is MySQL-specific, other DBs use different syntax for type casting. And "other DBs" use case-sensitive `collation` by default. So, probably, Rails team does not consider it as "common enough need". Moreover, I haven't find even `COLLATE` usage in ActiveRecord sources(except for schema definition), despite `COLLATE` is much more _common_ across DB, than `binary`.

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk, I gather from your comments that the brief answer to my question is NO. If so, would you go ahead and post a response? I'd like to see this question resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In short: there is NO `ActiveRecord` idiom for case-**sensitive**
>   search.
>
> ---
>
> For case-**insensitive** search you can try to use
>   [this](https://dogsnog.blog/2013/12/05/yes-rails-supports-case-insensitive-database-queries/).
>   It still works, but source code was changed a bit. So, use it on your
>   own risk.

In general, case sensitivity is subset of the [Collation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collation) idiom.
And different DBMS use very different *default* collations for string(text) data types, including default case *sensitivity*.
[Detailed description](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/15254) for MySQL.

There is a sql operator `COLLATE` which is very common across DBMS(but seems still is not in SQL Standard).
But `ActiveRecord` sources show it only in schema creation code.
Neither `ActiveRecord`, nor `Arel` gems do not use `COLLATE` in `where` search(sad).

**Note:** Please, don't miss the database tag(`mysql` etc) in a Question.
There are many Questions and Answers on SO without the tags(or with `sql` one), which are completely irrelevant for the **most** of DBMSs except author's one.

Comment: I had initially avoided the `mysql` tag on purpose because the essence of my question was NOT db-specific. I was seeking a functionality that could have been provided by AR, such that one would not have to worry about the specific database syntax. Anyhow, tag added now.

Comment: I left the note not for you only: I've really spent "a tons" of time on SO, understanding what DBMS Q/A was related to. Hint: DBMS(especially postgresql :) ) tag also triggers some good SO members to answer even they don't know Rails.